# Select top entry per ID from data table - SQL

Tags: sql

Assuming I have the following data table:

```
ID       VALUE 
---      ------- 
123      a
123      b
456      c
456      d
789      e
```

How can I get the output to only select the top entry per ID, assuming the data is already ordered. Ie, I need the data to show:

```
ID       VALUE
---      -------
123      a
456      c
789      e
```

Comment: which database system? mySQL? Oracle? SqLite? etc. Anyway off the top of my head try `SELECT ID, MIN(Value) FROM table GROUP BY ID` (assuming that the "top entry" as you describe it is always a letter of the alphabet earlier in the alphabet than all the other letters provided for that ID. I say this because SQL tables have no inherent ordering, so you can't rely on the order of items in the table, SQL doesn't guarantee it will use it in a SELECT)

Comment: What database are you using? SQL isn't a language so much as a class of languages, and the answer will depend on what specific variant you're using.

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering to the table, unless you have a column that specifies the ordering.

This is fundamental in SQL.  Let me assume you have an ordering column.  Then you can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.ordcol = (select max(t2.ordcol) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can add the ordering dynamically,

e.g.

```
select * from 

(select id, value, dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY value asc) as myrank from #mytable ) aa

where myrank=1
```